# WCF Deployment on windows server 2012

Tags: asp.net, wcf, deployment, wcf-data-services, windows-server-2012-r2

I have made an WCF service application and a MVC4 web application.my service uses my web membership provider functions to validate user and my provider uses entity framework to facilitate this validation.Locally when I run multiple projects as starup and use my application with services, it works perfectly.Now I have deployed this web service on windows 2012 server following these steps : 
  [Enable Wcf on windows server 2012](http://egeek.dk/enable-wcf-windows-server-2012/).But the problem is that I am getting the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have even added `system.web.razor` in my references of web service but still the problem is there. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on **System.Web.WebPages** and select properties. Set **Copy local** to true. Then publish again and the dll will be copied to the bin folder of the target.